# how to use weakreference on a vector

Tags: android, weak-references

How do I make a weakreference of a bitmapvector?

Let say I have this vector:

```
private Bitmap[] scaledBitmap = new Bitmap[9];
```

I could easily put the hole vector in a weakreference like this:

```
private WeakReference <Bitmap[]> scaledBitmapW;
this.scaledBitmapW = new WeakReference <Bitmap[]> (scaledBitmap);
```

But later in a method where I scaledown bitmaps and return those, how could I retrieve
each bitmap from the weakreference? Before I was even thinking of weakreference It looked like this:

```
scaledBitmap[i] = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bm.get(), reqW[i], reqH[i], true);
```

how to use **this.scaledBitmapW.get()** for all nine bitmaps?

Comment: Why would you like to use a `WeakReference` for ? If this is for the purpose of caching Bitmap objects, this is not a good idea on Android. Look at this part of the developer doc for more detailed infos : http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/cache-bitmap.html. Using an `LruCache` object to keep a reference to your bitmaps would be far more efficient.

Comment: I have a memoryleak in my app and i suspect that those images are not garbagecollected

Comment: What makes you say you have a memory leak related to your Bitmaps ?

Comment: Not for sure but according to DDMS and MAT in Eclipse it seems so.